# My Supercycle chain keeps breaking randomly

Tags: chain

I have an almost brand new Supercycle bike and for some reason, the chain keeps breaking on it. What could I be doing wrong

Comment: What model bike, and how are you riding it? On road or off? Aggressively or casual?

Comment: And have you actually put a new chain on or kept trying to put the damaged one back together?

Comment: And is it one particular link that keeps breaking, or various links are breaking?

Comment: After 24 hours without clarification of some important questions I don't think this can be answered. VTC but I'll retract if the missing information is added

Answer (score 1):

You have a low quality bike. The low quality shows as failures in various parts, in your case the chain. An immediate solution would be to replace it (either chain or the entire bike) with a decent quality one. No need to go fancy and expensive, anything that is sold in a bike shop should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

SuperCycle is the housebrand of a range of extremely inexpensive bicycles sold by Canadian Tire, a discount warehouse store.

The retail price is Canadian $109 or so. To get to this price point, the cheapest possible parts, the absolute worst materials, and the minimalist of assembly attention is used.

[image: supercycle]

So basically you can expect things to break or be impossible to adjust to work properly. In bicycling parlance, we call these “ride once put away (ROPO)” bikes or Bicycle Shaped Objects ([bso](/questions/tagged/bso)).

You could replace the chain with a better one but next week the brakes are likely to fail, or the wheel bearings. It’s very expensive to keep a BSO running and at some point (perhaps now) you’re better off trying to return it if you’re within the return policy and getting a good used bike from your local dealer.

Comment: Reminds me of some YouTube videos, where people took BSOs for trail riding. Incredible fun to watch.

Answer (score 0):

The cheapest and easier fix, is to replace the broken link with a 'quick link'. This way you shouldn't have to break the chain and weaken it.

The best fix is to get a new chain. Any cheap chain will do.

Over time chains tend to elongate, just a little. If the material is not tiptop then it will suffer some small fractures and corrosion will set on it. As it will corrode over time, said fractures will open more and stretch, on every single link on your chain. Even though it will look fine from afar.

When you break a link it is only the first warning to change an overdue chain.

Comment: Could you elaborate why braking would weaken the chain? Also, do you have any source of information about the fractures?

Comment: @ojs sorry for my bad english, was a in breaking something.

Comment: This doesn't really fit with "almost brand new" though. I've worn  chains beyond what's reasonable in the past (and I was heavy then as well as prone to pulling away hard in a high gear) but I've never snapped a chain. The snapped chain I helped fix recently was nearly new as well.

Comment: @ChrisH then its possible that the pin wasn’t in the right position when you joined the links. This has happened to me a couple of times in the past. Specially with half-link chains, as they are harder to join.

Comment: @dmb I don't know. I'd only met the rider for the first time a few minutes before the chain snapped. I've changed a good few chains myself, the old fashioned way with never a problem.

Comment: Chain breaking is usually *last* indication that it needs to be replaced, not the first.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus You are right, but just for the record I said "Overdue"(Overdone maybe?). The first sign in my opinion is extra movement when you bend the chain laterally or twist it. Less empirical, but good enough method, is the lack of "solid feel" when you move the chain with your hands, like the links have gaps beteween them.

Comment: @dmb, or just use a $10 Park Took Chain Checker

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus Second that, but sometimes said tools can be a pain in the butt to find them in South America. Hell is even hard to find a decent chain at the right price point. Some stuff is cheaper if I just order trought amazon...which makes me back to the question... a quick google search for "supercycle" came up with cheap bikes, that's why i've avoided speciallity tools, seems like over kill for this. Also thanks for the edit :)